# Identity scaffolding error: "There was an error running the selected code generator: ..."

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a scaffolded identity in Visual Studio 2022 for my ASP.NET Core MVC project, but getting this error:

[image: Initial error message]

(It doesn't even fit on my 2 screens)

There is a video which suggests creating a new solution with the same name, copy-pasting the DbContext, scaffolding there and coping the created files back to the original project.

Well, I tried that as well:

[image: New MVC project structure]

But it also failed with a smaller error message:

[image]

I have 8.0 version of .NET (currently preview version) with all required packages (Identity.EntityFrameworkCore, EntityFrameworkCore, EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer) updated to the latest version (also preview).

Both projects build successfully, no error messages.

Comment: Have you tried to scaffolding in a default mvc app,it seems the error is caued by your current dbcontext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that the problem was related to the primary constructors feature added in C# 12 (which is currently the preview version).

As you can see, scaffolding doesn't work when there're classes with primary constructors:

[image]

But it works great without them:

[image]

For some reason, code generator perceives primary constructors as syntax errors.

Btw, same goes for another new feature in C# 12:

[image]